# undefined index errors PHP

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked a lot and so I followed the responses but the error still persists.

Here's the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cf_name in C:\wamp\www\Mentalist Magician\contact.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: cf_email in C:\wamp\www\Mentalist Magician\contact.php on line 4
```

etc..

Here's my code:

```
 <?php


 $field_cf_name = $_POST['cf_name']; $field_cf_email =
 $_POST['cf_email']; $field_cf_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
 $field_cf_client = $_POST['cf_client'];

 if(isset($_POST['cf_name'])){ $field_cf_name = $_POST['cf_name']; }

if(isset($_POST['cf_email'])){ $field_cf_email = $_POST['cf_email']; }

if(isset($_POST['cf_message'])){ $field_cf_message =
 $_POST['cf_message']; } if(isset($_POST['cf_client'])){
 $field_cf_client = $_POST['cf_client']; } 

 if (empty($field_cf_name) && empty($field_cf_email) &&
 empty($field_cf_cellphone) && empty($field_cf_message)) {
     echo 'Please fill in all required fields';
     return false; }

 else{ //process the rest of the form }

 if($field_cf_client != ''){
     echo "Submission Sent - Thank you!";   return false; }

 else{ //process the rest of the form }

 $mail_to = 'info@test.com';

 $subject = 'New Message From Client'; $headers = "From: " .
 strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n"; $headers .= "Reply-To: ".
 strip_tags($field_email) . "\r\n"; $headers .= "MIME-Version:
 1.0\r\n"; $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 $body_message = '<html><body style="font-family:calibri,sans-serif;
 font-size:18px">'; $body_message .= '<h2 style="font-weight:600;
 font-size:27px; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
 padding-bottom:10px;">New Message From Your Website</h2>';
 $body_message .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600;
 ">Client Name:</strong> '.$field_cf_name."</p>\n"."\n"; $body_message
 .= '<p><strong style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Email:</strong>
 '.$field_cf_email."</p>\n"."\n"; $body_message .= '<p><strong
 style="color:#000; font-weight:600; ">Message:</strong>
 '.$field_cf_message."</p>\n"."\n";

 $body_message .= '</body></html>';

 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers); ?>
```

Form Code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" data-validate="parsley">
                <label>Name</label><span class="red">*</span><br/>
                <input name="cf_name" type="text" data-required="true" class="form-text2" />
                <br/><br/><label>Email Address</label><span class="red">*</span><br/>
                <input name="cf_email" type="text" data-required="true" data-type="email" class="form-text2" />
                <br/><br/><label>Message</label><span class="red">*</span><br/>
                <textarea name="cf_message" data-required="true" cols="" rows="" class="form-msg"></textarea>

                 <!-- Client Website -->
                 <input id="client" class="taken" name="cf_client" type="text"  />   
                 <!-- END -->

                <p><input name="Submit" class="submit2" value="Submit" type="submit" /> echo "<div id="submitmessage">Message Sent!</div>"</p>  </form>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Comment: How is this script used? Is it the page that is used as action in a form on another page, or is this form embedded in this page?

Comment: Sorry i'll post my form code now!

Comment: This code is very hard to read. Please format it. (Replace any tabs with spaces before copying to SO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a variable or index that does not exists triggers a notice in PHP, and when your error reporting is on E_ALL, that notice is visible.

The problem with putting your input-variables (in this case POST) in another variable is that you are never sure they exist, because they depend on user input. The solution is to check if they exist, e.g. with `isset`.

Gives a notice:

```
<?php
$field_cf_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
```

Does not give a notice:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cf_name'])) {
    $field_cf_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
}
```

Comment: Or simply you can suppress warning using $field_cf_name = @$_POST['cf_name']; ($field_cf_name will be null if $_POST['cf_name'] is not present.)

Comment: Notices do not exists because the people who created PHP wanted to annoy you. They are there for a good reason. You should be very aware of the fact that a variable can be non-existent.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorted! :)

Comment: Just a quick question - if I want to echo, "message sent!" when the user clicks submit, would this work - <?php echo ['Message Sent!']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't fixed everything:

```
 $field_cf_name = $_POST['cf_name']; $field_cf_email =
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- no isset() checks on this
```

and this is at the EXACT lines of code where the warnings are issued for.